# Angular Material Drag and drop in a table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I have a problem with Angular Material:
I need in my Table a drag and drop function but it doesn't work.

**this is my component.ts code:**

```
dropTable(event: CdkDragDrop <test[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.childTest.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  this.childTestTable.renderRows();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually updating the data when using the cdkDragDrop on Material Tables is a little wonky, unfortunately. I have created a working poc which you could look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/table-drag-n-drop

The important thing is the table data need to be manually updated, here is my drop-function:

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
  moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
} else {
  transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                    event.container.data,
                    event.previousIndex,
                    event.currentIndex);
}

// updates moved data and table, but not dynamic if more dropzones
this.dataSource.data = clonedeep(this.dataSource.data);
this.dataSource2.data = clonedeep(this.dataSource2.data);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I tried your code but doesn't work by me

Comment: Then I guess you should post a complete example of what is not working, since it is working in that poc 

Comment: Hi @LarsRødal, this is working but I need to keep track of the initial array of data. With clonedeep this is not possible, I've tried creating in ngOnInit a mattabledatasource called "initialData" but it is changed too after the rearrangement of the items.

Comment: Yeah, you need to make a cloneDeep to re-render the list, if don't do that, you will not get the right privouseIndex and currentIndex when making a next drag. Unfortunately, I don't know why.

Comment: You can avoid cloning the datasources by explicitly updating the tables:

    this.table1.renderRows();
    this.table2.renderRows();

Answer (score 0):

Your list has to be marked with `cdkDropList` and a binding to `[cdkDropListData]="data"`. If you want to drag an item from one list to another you have to connect them with `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="ids"`

In component.ts try:

```
moveItemInArray(
  event.container.data,
  event.previousIndex,
  event.currentIndex);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have **cdkDropList** and **cdkDropListData** in my mat-table. I also added event.container.data but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For a working **GitHub** project and a detailed explanation please check this blog [Angular Material Drag/Drop Table](https://andorlogicfilter.blogspot.com/2022/07/material-dragdrop-table-in-this-post-we.html)

**app.component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drag($event)">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      {{column.header}}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{column.cell(row)}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" cdkDrag></tr>
</table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<any>;

drag(event: CdkDragDrop<PeriodicElement[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.dataSource, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    this.table.renderRows();
}
```

**renderRows** method will update the dataSource in mat-table.

**Result:**

[image: Before Drag/Drop]

[image: After Drag/Drop]